# How can I get a function pointer to a template method of a template class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a template class

```
template <typename ... _AttributeExtensions>
class SomeServiceProxy
    : virtual public SomeService,
      virtual public SomeServiceProxyBase,
      virtual public _AttributeExtensions... {
```

which has the following method:

```
template <typename ... _AttributeExtensions>
void SomeServiceProxy<_AttributeExtensions...>::subscribeSomething(CommonAPI::CallStatus &_internalCallStatus, DataTypes::OperationStatus &_operationStatus, const CommonAPI::CallInfo *_info) {
    delegate_->subscribeSomething(_internalCallStatus, _operationStatus, _info);
}
```

What I am trying, but qualified name is not allowed :

```
typedef ( DataTypes::OperationStatus) (SomeServiceProxy::*subscribeCall) (void);
```

Is there any way to get a function pointer to this method?

Comment: Even ignoring the `template` part, the `return` type and parameter list are different in `subscribeSomething` and your function pointer.

Comment: C++ has member functions rather than methods. `SomeServiceProxy` however isn't one. It is a template. You cannot have a pointer to a template.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a template alias for your member function pointer too.
Using "using" instead of typedef allows you to do that.

```
template<typename... extensions>
class SomeServiceProxy
{
public:
    void DoSomething() {};
};

template<typename... extensions>
using DoSomethingFnPtr = void (SomeServiceProxy<extensions...>::*)();

int main()
{
    SomeServiceProxy<int, int> proxy;
    DoSomethingFnPtr<int,int> memfnptr = &SomeServiceProxy<int, int>::DoSomething;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and if for example I want to have a method with arguments like void DoSomething2(int a) ?

Comment: It will become tricky if DoSomething itself will be templated otherwise it will look like 
`template<typename ...extensions> using DoSomethingFnPtr = void(SomeServiceProxy<extensions...>::*)(int);`